# Split-button dropdown line wrap on screen resize and option selection

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I am using split-button dropdowns, and I am wondering if there is way to stop the wrapping of the dropdown button?

Before, I had

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block"> // btn-block
```

And the split button would wrap even when the screen was resized:

[image]

But I was able to find a fix for that ([GitHub Issue Link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10354))

```
<div class="btn-group" style="width:100px;"> // Removed btn-block class, added style
```

[image]

But now if I select an option from the Dropdown, it becomes wrapped again, regardless of the screen size/column width (*this issue was not there when I had the btn-block class as long as there was enough room in the column*):

[image]

I would like the dropdown to not wrap regardless of the screen size or the option selected. Also, I do have the width of the columns set using col-md-*

Also, when a long option is selected, it starts to overlap into the next column:
[image]

I hope I have provided enough information to initiate meaningful responses.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ishq786/t9r6wh8d/1/)

```
<div class="col-lg-10" id="mapColumn">
<div>
<table class="table table-condensed tablesaw tablesaw-stack table-striped-column" data-tablesaw-mode="stack" id="table2">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="col-md-2">Map Actions</th>
  <th class="col-md-2">DB Actions</th>
  <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
  <th class="col-md-3">Name</th>
  <th class="col-md-3">Features</th>
  <th class="col-md-1">Rating</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
  <td>
    <!-- <div class="btn-group btn-block"> -->
    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Actions</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="mapActions">
        <li><a>TOGGLE Map</a></li>
        <li><a>ROTATE View</a></li>
        <li><a>SAVE Pic to PC</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>
    <!-- <div class="btn-group btn-block"> -->
    <div class="btn-group" style="width:100px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Actions</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dbActions">
        <li><a>UPDATE Features</a></li>
        <li><a>SAVE POV to DB</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td>123456</td>
  <td>Street A & Street B and a very very very long name</td>
  <td>
    <span class="label label-success">Label One</span>
    <span class="label label-success">Label Two</span>
    <span class="label label-success">Label Three</span>
    <span class="label label-success">Label Four</span>
  </td>
  <td>★★★★★</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the info. I have added some html code. Should I add the css and JS in the question as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add these styles:

```css
.btn-group {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}
.btn-group-vertical>.btn, .btn-group>.btn {
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

Basically this makes the `.btn` elements inline, which in turn allows it to take advantage of `nowrap` white spacing.  I also had to set the button group to `font-size:none` to remove the spacing between the buttons, but Twitter Bootstrap sets a non-relative, pixel value for button font size, so setting `font-size:0` on the `.btn-group` shouldn't be a problem.  I removed the floating from the `.btn`s and, lastly, removed the fixed width of `100px` in the markup.

https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/b4qtrfmb/

#### Edit:

Alternatively, you should also be able to use `display:flex`

```css
.btn-group, .btn-group-vertical {
  display:flex;
}
.btn-group-vertical>.btn, .btn-group>.btn {
  display:inline-flex;
  float:none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/b4qtrfmb/1/

Comment: Thanks Joseph! It is working on the JSFiddle, I will try it on my actual code and report back later today.

Comment: @Ali Cool.  I anticipate checking back here every now and again over the next 5 hours or so.  Otherwise I can jump on late tonight and answer any question you may have asked in my absence.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I think it is working. I'll accept the answer and comment back if I have any issues later on. Thanks again!